# Using of Binary Search

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, number-theory

I have given an Range **L to R**. I have to find out the how many numbers are there between L to R such that **number is having an odd number of divisors**.

```
1<L<R<10^18
```

Since L and R are quite high so simple for loop will result in timeout.
I found that **Binary Search** can be used in solving this problem.
I could not understand how  binary search is helping in finding the count of a numbers who are having odd number of divisor.
**Code:**

```
int find (long long n) {
    int low,high,mid;
    long long v1,v2;
    low = 1;
    high = 1e9 + 1;
    if (n == 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    while (low <= high) {
        mid = (low + high) / 2;
        v1 = mid * 1LL * mid;
        v2 = (mid + 1) * 1LL * (mid + 1);
        if (v1 <= n) {
            if (v2 > n) {
                return mid;
            } else {
                low = mid + 1;
            }
        } else {
            high = mid - 1;
        }
    }
}
```

And
Answer : `ans = find(r) - find(l - 1);`
PLease Explain the concept of Binary Search in Number Theory

Answer (score 3):

This algorithm is based on the simple fact that in order to have an odd number of divisors the number `n` must be a full square. Otherwise for every divisor `k` there's also another distinct divisor `n/k`, so you will always have an even number of divisors. This algorithm just counts number of full squares between `1` and supplied `n` (inclusive), which is actually the [integer square root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_square_root) (`floor(sqrt(n))`). So it finds the square root using binary search. If you have the `sqrt(n)` method on your platform/language which is precise enough, you can solve your problem like this:

```
ans = floor(sqrt(r)) - floor(sqrt(l-1));
```

Usually the `double` type doesn't provide enough precision, so the result could be one less or one more. Probably that's the reason why binary search was used. Nevertheless you can still use `sqrt`. Just calculate the square after that and if necessary adjust the result by one (it would be much faster). Alternatively you may use the Newton method (it would be slower than `sqrt` with adjustment, but much faster than binary search).

Answer (score 0):

for a number **N**, Suppose ***d*** is divisor of **N**. Then there is always a number **N/d** which can divide **N**. 
A number have odd number of divisor only when in some case `d = (N/d)`

Example:
If `N = 16`

if divisor `d=1` then `N/d = 16`

if divisor  `d=2` then `N/d = 8`

if divisor  `d=4` then `N/d = 4`

So, if we want to know the number which has odd numbers of divisor between **R** and **L**, we need to know how much numbers is square number between this range.

Number of square number less than or equal to R is **= square_root(R)**

Number of square number less than(as L is inclusive) L is **= square_root(L-1)**

```
So answer = floor(square_root(R))-floor(square_root(L-1))
```

As we need only integer part so we take floor.